# AS3 Starling stagewebview cant access content

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I have setup a starling project and added stagewebview to embed Google maps. I have tested the project using Facebook and it seems to load http://facebook.com correctly. The issue I am having is I am unable to access the page (click links, log in etc).

I don't know if I understand the use of stagewebview or if something else is stopping me from accessing the content. My understanding is you can load an external page into the project/device.

The project will be used in a mobile app that uses maps. If someone knows of a better way to using Google maps (or any other mapping software) in a mobile (iOS and Android) I am all ears.

Thanks

Comment: You're better off building your app with HTML and JavaScript. It will save you a lot of pain.

Comment: That was the next option if this can't be done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loading Google maps into a stageWebView certainly is possible. Although I used StageWebViewBridge as I needed communication both ways between ActionScript and JavaScript.

[StageWebViewBridge loading and communicating with online page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8449596/stagewebviewbridge-loading-and-communicating-with-online-page)

Be aware though that the stageWebView won't be on the Starling (Stage3D) display list. It will  need to sit above on the Flash NativeStage.

For mobile you could look into using an ANE to access mapping APIs.

http://sleepydesign.blogspot.co.uk/2012/07/ane-free-air-native-extensions.html

http://code.google.com/p/air-maps-ane/

Or Distriqt sell a range of ANE's, mapping included.

http://labs.distriqt.com/native-extensions

Comment: Thanks for the info. I have tried the .ane at code.google.com but can't get it to work. Keep getting a blank white page with MAP_READY EMRTP EMRTP so not sure whats up. Have successfully integrated MapQuest so maybe that could be the way to go.

Comment: Thanks. I have previously purchased Distriqts ANE (brilliant package) but the maps is just new as it isn't included in the previous download I got from them. Hopefully they will allow access to it.

Comment: @Kere, I've only just seen this but you'll definitely have access to the maps ANE. Contact us and we'll show you how to grab it!